# What is POSIX? Which standards they are?

Tags: operating-system, posix

I am a student of BSCS and going through a course of Operating Systems, In my text book, i came across POSIX but never understood clearly that what it is and where is it used? On wiki it says that it is the set of standards, which set? and which standards? It would be great if anyone could come up with an answer that can fade my confusion away, Thank you.

Comment: You can read all about it in great detail at [their web page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand POSIX you have to understand UNIX. UNIX was an operating system created in the 1970s and was unique in that many different companies and institutions were free to create their own version.

This, of course, created a problem: Not all UNIXs had the same APIs, and thus sometimes software would break going from one UNIX to the other. As a result, a committee got together and created a set of standards that they hoped all flavors of UNIX would adopt, so that software could be easily ported from one type to the other. The result was POSIX.

Practically every modern UNIX distribution supports POSIX, including several Unix-like and non-Unix operating systems. For example, Microsoft Windows with some purchasable extensions from Microsoft supports POSIX.